# no matching route for show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a no-route matches error in a Rails application that uses omniauth to sign in with Twitter. I started the application following along with a Railscast, in which the logged in Twitter user was created in a sessions controller like this

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def create
  twitteruser = Twitteruser.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  session[:twitteruser_id] = twitteruser.id
  redirect_to twitterquestions_url, notice: "Signed in!"
end
```

I created a table to store the users Twitter information like this

```
def change
    create_table :twitterusers do |t|
      t.string :provider
      t.string :uid
      t.string :name
      t.string :image

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

this is a databaseentry

```
=> [#<Twitteruser id: 1, provider: "twitter", uid: "1121308772", name: "mytwitteraccou t", image: "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3164285746/.", created_at: "2013-02-12 23:52:44", updated_at: "2013-02-12 23:52:44">]
```

I also created a Twitterusers controller like this so that I could show a user

```
class TwitterusersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @twitteruser = Twitteruser.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

In the routes file

```
resources :twitterusers
```

Based on the output of rake routes, I created a link to the currentusers profile like this (and also added a show.html.erb file in the view)

```
<li>Signed in as <%= link_to "current_user.name", twitteruser_path %>!</li>
```

Rake routes

```
twitterusers GET    /twitterusers(.:format)                         twitterusers#index
                         POST   /twitterusers(.:format)                         twitterusers#create
         new_twitteruser GET    /twitterusers/new(.:format)                     twitterusers#new
        edit_twitteruser GET    /twitterusers/:id/edit(.:format)                twitterusers#edit
             twitteruser GET    /twitterusers/:id(.:format)                     twitterusers#show
                         PUT    /twitterusers/:id(.:format)                     twitterusers#update
                         DELETE /twitterusers/:id(.:format)                     twitterusers#destroy
```

When I got that error, I wondered if it had to do with the fact that the user was created in sessions_controller, so I then created a show action in the sessions controller

sessions_controller

```
def show
    @twitteruser = Twitteruser.find(params[:id])
end
```

and created a sessions resources in routes

```
resources :sessions
```

and then based on rake routes I created the following link

Signed in as <%= link_to "current_user.name", session_path %>!

but got the same error

```
sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)                             sessions#index
                         POST   /sessions(.:format)                             sessions#create
             new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                         sessions#new
            edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)                    sessions#edit
                 session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)                         sessions#show
                         PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)                         sessions#update
                         DELETE
```

There were already these routes in session controller

```
  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<%= link_to "current_user.name", twitteruser_path %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to current_user.name, twitteruser_path(current_user) %>
```

and modify this section to only render if `current_user` is populated:

```
<% if current_user %>
  Your link here
<% end %>
```